# validate client side by model dataannotations, executed on razor view field onchange event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

i have already validated my model and works fine.. but only when i press submit button...

i want to trigger the validation when the user change values...

i have a datepicker by editorfor

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "trigger validation here" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

i used the form.submit(); and works fine.. but i dont want submit until the client press the submit button

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Else you can use the following to disable validation for a particular input by adding a `data-val='false'`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new {  @data_val = "false" } })
```

and use the following in the submit button code, or validate it manually in during submission

```
     var form = $( "#thisform" );
     form.validate();
     if (form.valid()) {
    // ...
     }
```

**Edit:**

You could try this to disable validation (for all fields) for particular events on the jQuery Validation plugin for client side validation using the following code:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onsubmit: true
})
```

OR

```
$("#myform").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onsubmit: true
});
```

Refer: https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/
and 
https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: well.. its working, but im looking for a way to use default datavalidation... if somene have another suggestion, i will really apreciated

Comment: I have updated my answer to do this using Jquery Validation plugin settings.